# Spring JPA Repository accessing fields from Object collection

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have the next entity:

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private int age;
  private Address address;
}
```

I'm using Spring JPA Repositories to query the database. So, I have a `List<Person>` to retrieve from the database. I have the next query working:

```
List<Person> findByNameAndAge(String name, int age);
```

What I want to do is to pass the whole `List<Person>` to not call the previous method many times and, just query the database in one call. Something like this:

```
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE (p.name, p.int) IN (:list.name, :list.int)")
List<Person> findByNameAndAge(@Param("list") List<Person> personList);
```

Comment: Why not sending two collection names and ints instead of List of persons?

Comment: I think the query you have in `@Query` isn't really what you want to do. What's your aim: 1. get people with either name X or name M or age Y or age N and so on...    2. get people with (name X and age Y) or (name M and age N) and so on...  Your version of the query would do the first, not the second

Comment: @YCF_L I tried it but, is not working as expected because, if I pass for example `Names["Joe", "Jane"]  Ages[22,  25]` and  let's say the database contains two Joes, one with 22 and other with 25 years, I just want to retrieve the one with 22 years.

Comment: @Sindbad90 I want to retrieve the people with (name = x and age = y)(name = a and age = b) and so on, the second point you mentioned.

Comment: @YCF_L Yes but, what I really need to know here, if there's a way to access object field from the query method from the collection of objects in the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the discussions in the comments, I understand that you expect the generated query to be something like this:

```sql
SELECT p FROM Person p 
WHERE (p.name, p.int) IN ((:p.name1, :p.age1), (:p.name2, :p.age2), ...)
```

I think there's a crude way to do it:

```java
@Query("SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE (p.name, p.age) IN (:params)")
List<Person> findByNameAndAge(@Param("params") List<Object[]> params);
```

where, `params` is a list of `tuples`:

```
param[0] = name1, param[1] = age1,
param[0] = name2, param[1] = age2,
..
```

Pls try it out and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: I tried that but, there's a huge problem with this approach in my case. How can I create a tuple of different types? In my real case scenario, I need a tuple of `[String, BigInteger]`

Comment: Okay, yes I missed that. Again, I'm not sure about this but can you try List<Object[]>?

Comment: do have a demo project that you can share with the above setup

Comment: Oh boy, I wish I could share the project but, is a private project. :(

Comment: Can I debug the actual queries being written by Spring to see if the values are being passed correctly?

Comment: I understand that, if you could probably replicate only the relevant stuff (single Person class, Person repository, etc). Will help us debug it faster.

Comment: Yeah try printing the queries maybe: These might help: `logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG`, `logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE`, and `logging.level.org.hibernate.type=TRACE`

Comment: I've seen that the query generated is somehitng like... `WHERE (x, y) IN (?, ?)`, That means that the tuple is being passed correctly? I'm going to try with just one parameter or two but, with the same data type just to discard it is a parsing or mapping problem from the Object[]

Comment: No, I tried with a String[] but nothing, it doesn't find any result.

Comment: I guess you might have to fallback to `NamedParameterJdbcTemplate`.

Comment: @Sinbad90 I'm trying a different approach. I'm concatenating the string and the BigInteger field in a single string, I have just one issue, the BigInteger is converted to a string with two decimal points. Do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: Do you have the code to show how you're concatenating the values? PS: I would suggest against this approach, though; use `JdbcTemplate` to accomplish this.

Comment: I guess is due to the H2 database. I'm using it for testing and the BigInteger is being parsed to string with two decimal numbers.

Comment: In case you're using H2, it's possible that our approach with `List<Object[]>` might be failing due to lack of support for an "in-clause" on multiple columns. I may be wrong here, but that's a possibility.

Comment: Yes, that's a big possibility. I'll try connected to a different DB